# Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context trying to give a size to a scroll view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to separate the UI elements from my view controller, so I create a UIView declaring all my UI elements, and one element is a scrollView, and that throws the error

```
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scroll
    }()
```

How to solve **Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context**

And how to give a size to the scroll view?

Do I need to declare the scrollview in my view controller?

Comment: I would think about that error message: "The expression type is ambiguous without more context."  Why might an expression type in that line of code be ambiguous?  Is `scroll.contentSize` the same type that `CGSize()` returns?

Comment: according to the definition in the header the `contentSize` is  a `CGSize`, you mean that?

Comment: `self` is a `UIView`. `UIView`s don't have a `view` property. Also please don't post pictures of code or errors – update your question with the code and error as text.

Comment: Sorry about the format. You're right I know it doesn't have a view, but how to give the size of the scroll view, I tried with `self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height`, I don't know if it's right? because my scroll doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error **Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context**

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
```